# Pagination in php mvc(jream)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pdo, pagination

sometimes last year i went through a php mvc tutorial done by jream the platform looks so simple and convenient. Now am building a web application with this mvc platform and now am stoked in the aspect of pagination, while trying to paginate records from the  PDO database.

source codes below.

**model:**

```
function paginate() {

    $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
    $perPage = isset($_GET['per-page']) && $_GET['per-page'] <= 50 ? (int) $_GET['per-page'] : 5;

    $start=($page > 1) ? ($page * $perPage) - $perPage :0;
    $articles = $this->db->prepare("Select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id,title from   tblpost limit {$start},{$perPage}");

    $articles->execute();

    $articles = $articles->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $total = $this->db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total")->fetch()    ['total'];
   return $pages =  ceil($total / $perPage);
   }
```

**controller:**

```
    function index() {
    $this->view->title = "Home";
    $this->view->home = $this->model->loadpost();
    $this->view->pgcount= $this->model->paginate();
    $this->view->render("index/index");
    }
```

**view:**

```
<div>
<?php for($x=1;$x <= $pages; $x++): ?> 
<a href="#"><?php echo $x;?></a>
<?php endfor; ?>
</div>
```

i need to make the post paginate using this particular php mvc

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: how can i paginate posts on my index page